# AddUserIdToMytimes .. Error - SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "mytimes" ADD "user_id" integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migrate

i try this to tap into the terminal :

rails generate migration AddUserIdToMytimes user_id:integer 
--> create

db:migrate

--> -- add_column(:mytimes, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "mytimes" ADD "user_id" integer

What could ill do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `Mytime` model already have `user_id` field.

What could you do? Remove this migration as unnecessary?